# Does google get my data if I am using Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Pardon for being a novice at this 
If I am using Google Maps API to overlay addresses on maps, does it mean the data that i use will be accessible to Google?

Is there anyway to circumvent this issue?

I am overlaying mortgages from a client to google maps, however I don't want to share data with Google as it is confidential !!

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since they are plotting your location on a map, they apparently know where you are. Whether or not you believe their maps privacy policy is your decision:

http://www.google.com/maps/about/behind-the-scenes/streetview/privacy/